# Matching blocks with conditions

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am in the need for some regexp guru help.

I am trying to make a small config system for a home project, but for this it seams that I need a bit more regexp code than my regexp skills can come up with.

I need to be able to extract some info inside blocks based on conditions and actions. For an example.

```
action1 [condition1 condition2 !condition3] {
    Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3
}
```

The conditions are stored in simple variables separated by space. I use these variables to create the regexp used to extract the block info from the file. Most if this is working fine, except that I have no idea how to make the "not matching" part, which basically means that a "word" is not available in the condition variable.

```
VAR1="condition1 condition2"
VAR2="condition1 condition2 condition3"
```

When matched against the above, it should match VAR1 but not VAR2.

This is what I have so far

```
PARAMS="con1 con2 con3"
INPUT_PARAMS="[^!]\\?\\<$(echo $PARAMS | sed 's/ /\\>\\|[^!]\\?\\</g')\\>"

sed -n "/^$ACTION[ \t]*\(\[\($INPUT_PARAMS\)*\]\)\?[ \t]*{/,/}$/p" default.cfg | sed '/^[^{]\+{/d' | sed '/}/d'
```

Not sure how pretty this is, but it does work, except for not-matching.

**EDIT:**

Okay I will try to elaborate a bit.

Let's say that I have the below text/config file

```
action1 [con1 con2 con3] {
    Line A
    Line B
}

action2 [con1 con2 !con3] {
    Line C
}

action3 [con1 con2] {
    Line D
}

action4 {
    Line E
}
```

and I have the fallowing conditions to match against

```
ARG1="con1 con2 con3"
ARG2="con1 con2"
ARG3="con1"
ARG4="con1 con4"

# Matching against ARG1 should print Line A, B, D and E
# Matching against ARG2 should print Line C, D and E
# Matching against ARG3 should print Line E
# Matching against ARG4 should print Line E
```

Below is a java like example of action2 using normal conditional check. It give a better idea of what I am trying

```
if (ARG2.contains("con1") && ARG2.contains("con2") && !ARG2.contains("con3")) {
    // Print all lines in this block
}
```

Comment: I understand nothing. What are you trying to do ? Check for a match and know when not matched ?

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. sed is the right tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for any other text manipulation you should be using awk. Post some clear, precise sample input and expected output along with a description of the mapping and we can help you.

Comment: If what you are actually parsing is CSS, have you considered using an actual CSS parser?

Comment: It's not CSS. It's a custom built config file for a shell script that I am working on. It only looks like CSS, because I like having braces separate blocks. Mostly because I normally work with CSS, Java, JavaScript, PHP etc. So it seams familiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic of how you're selecting which records to print lines from isn't clear to me so here's how to create sets of positive and negative conditions using awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    RS = ""; FS = "\n"

    # create the set of the positive conditions in the "conds" variable.
    n = split(conds,tmp," ")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        wanted[tmp[i]]
}
{
    # create sets of the positive and negative conditions
    # present in the first line of the current record.
    delete negPresent   # use split("",negPresent) in non-gawk
    delete posPresent
    n = split($1,tmp,/[][ {]+/)
    for (i=2; i<n; i++) {
        cond = tmp[i]
        sub(/^!/,"",cond) ? negPresent[cond] : posPresent[cond]
    }

    allPosInWanted = 1
    for (cond in posPresent)
        if ( !(cond in wanted) )
            allPosInWanted = 0

    someNegInWanted = 0
    for (cond in negPresent)
        if (cond in wanted)
             someNegInWanted = 1

    if (allPosInWanted && !someNegInWanted)
        for (i=2;i<NF;i++)
            print $i
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v conds='con1 con2 con3' -f tst.awk file
    Line A
    Line B
    Line D
    Line E
$
$ awk -v conds='con1 con2' -f tst.awk file
    Line C
    Line D
    Line E
$
$ awk -v conds='con1' -f tst.awk file
    Line E
$
$ awk -v conds='con1 con4' -f tst.awk file
    Line E
$
```

and now you just have to code whatever logic you like in that final block where the printing is being done to compare the conditions in each of the sets.

Comment: This looks great. However, wanted should never be positive or negative, they are the available conditions. So what it should do is check whether all posPresent exists in conds and none of the negPresent exists in conds. If this is the case, then it should print all of the lines that resides within the two braces for that block. If not, then nothing from that block should be printed. Not sure how to do this with awk since I have never used it before. I knew that it was powerful, but I have not yet had the time to play around with it.

Comment: OK, I just coded what you described as a couple of loops on the present conditions with tests against the wanted conditions. Take a look at the solution now. If you just want the lines between `{...}` instead of the whole blocks, that's a trivial tweak. You could do this more briefly without the Present sets but they help clarity and allow you to code simple sanity checks if you like, such as checking for a condition being present in both posPresent and negPresent or a condition already being present in either set when populating them. Get the book: Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition.

Comment: Yes this is the behavior that I need. Of cause I need it to skip comments # and also only print the lines within the braces, but this gives me an idea of how awk works, so I will play further with this example. Thanks a lot for this :)

Comment: I just updated it to only print the lines within the blocks. If you update your sample input to add comments wherever they can appear, I can show you how to remove those if you like. If it's simply that you want to skip any line outside of the action blocks that starts with a `#` then just add a line to the above that says `/^#/{next}` and if there can be whitespace before it then make it `$1~/^#/{next}` but it might be trickier than it sounds since we're using blank lines as the record separators and a line containing a comment is not blank. I might have tackled this differently had I known.

Comment: Well my idea was to be able to add comments anywhere outside of the blocks. It is meant to be used for config files, and it can be useful in some cases to add comments to the different parts of the configuration. But thanks for this update, it is really great. And I will try the book that you mentioned, AWK seams to be a very handy tool when working with shell scripts.

Comment: That's fine, and it's trivial to handle, but there's always different ways to solve a problem and this may not be the best one if your input file has comments or anything else different from the sample you posted. In UNIX its important to know the purpose of each tool as they can similar on the surface and can each be used for trivial problems. In particular people get confused about when to use shell builtins, grep, sed, and awk. grep is for finding REs in a file, sed is for simple subsitutions on 1 line, awk is for all other text manipulation, and shell is just for sequencing calls to tools.

Comment: Well your example is working perfectly, and until I read a bit about awk, I am not touching it. The comments is easy enough to work around, I just added a sed that strippes away all comments and pipes the rest into your awk script. This is working fine and since this is just for a personal project, I am not so worried about how pretty this is. Thanks again for this very useful help.